# How to access root node using lxml python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have following xml:

```
xml1 = """

    <bookstore>
      <book>
        <title lang="en">Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
      </book>
      <book>
         <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
         <price>39.95</price>
     </book>
    </bookstore>
```

when I am using xpath on bookstore, it is returning empty list:

```
val = etree.parse(StringIO(xml1))
val.xpath('bookstore')
```

But it is working for other node like val.xpath('book').

what is wrong in retrieving bookstore element using xpath??

Answer (score 0):

Add "/" to your xpath query, like this:

```python
val.xpath("/bookstore")
```